# notifyDatasetChanged is not working inside the getView() method for Custom Adapter In Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am basically trying hide and show a text in the list row when I am clicking a button in the list row. I have added the onClick() for the button inside getView() method and then calling the notifyDataSetChanged(). But it is not working. No change in the text visibility. Here is my custom Adapter code:

```
  public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> mListQuestion = null;
    private List<String> mListAnswer = null;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    boolean flag = false;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> question, List<String> answer ) {
        this.mListQuestion = question;
        this.mListAnswer = answer;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return mListQuestion.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListQuestion.size();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_faq_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvQuestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.tvAns = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.anstext);
            holder.ivArrow = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_expand);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvQuestion.setText(mListQuestion.get(position));
        holder.tvAns.setText(mListAnswer.get(position));
        holder.ivArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (flag == false)
                    {
                        Logger.d("arrow clicked when flag is false");
                        holder.tvAns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.ivArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else if (flag == true)
                    {
                        Logger.d("arrow clicked when flag is true");
                        holder.tvAns.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.ivArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvQuestion;
        TextView tvAns;
        Button ivArrow;
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks in Advance.

-Arindam.

Comment: there is no meaning to call here `notifyDataSetChanged();` for your purpose

Comment: Can you please tell what else I can call to refresh the complete view?

Comment: I still don't understand what is your requirement here?

Comment: Its just simple, You are not making any changes in `dataSet`. `notifyDataSetChanged()` will only work if you are making changes in `dataSets`. Which is in your case `mListQuestion` and `mListAnswer`

Comment: Basically I am getting some questions and answers from server and which I am showing in a listview. By default the answers are invisible. Beside the each question, there is a small button of expand. Once user clicks the expand button, I am trying show the answer. Again on the next click, answer will be hidden.

Comment: Have you tried running application in debug Mode and add  break point to if condition in OnclickListener , is, it comming in?

Comment: @HourGlass I have already checked it by adding logs. control is coming inside when flag is true or false based on the expand button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> mListQuestion = null;
    private List<String> mListAnswer = null;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    private List<Boolean> textViewVisibileState; 

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> question, List<String> answer ) {
        this.mListQuestion = question;
        this.mListAnswer = answer;
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewVisibileState=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[getCount()]));
          Collections.fill(this.textViewVisibileState,false);
    } 

    @Override 
    public Object getItem(int position)
    { 
        return mListQuestion.get(position);
    } 

    @Override 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 

    @Override 
    public int getCount() { 
        return mListQuestion.size();
    } 

    @Override 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null)
        { 
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_faq_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvQuestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.tvAns = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.anstext);
            holder.ivArrow = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_expand);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } 

        holder.tvQuestion.setText(mListQuestion.get(position));
        holder.tvAns.setText(mListAnswer.get(position));
        if(textViewVisibileState.get(position))
{
            holder.tvAns.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.ivArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);

}
else
{
    Logger.d("arrow clicked when flag is false"); 
                        holder.tvAns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.ivArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);

}
        holder.ivArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        { 
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v)
                { 
                    if (textViewVisibileState.get(position))
                    { 
                        textViewVisibileState.set(position,false);
   } 
                    else
                    { 

                        textViewVisibileState.set(position,true);

 } 
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } 
        }); 

        return convertView;
    } 


    static class ViewHolder { 
        TextView tvQuestion;
        TextView tvAns;
        Button ivArrow;
    } 

}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `flag` is not context sensitive to object `holder`. So `flag` is always = false in your case.  How about `setVisibility(View.GONE)` initially? And then `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` ONLY when ivArrow is clicked upon.

Comment: I have checked that falg is not false always. When I am clicking expand button, flag is becoming true and it is going inside the condition.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee, Sorry, I see now that you're changing the value of flag. But still, I think it is not the correct logic. I suggest setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) when the user clicks on the arrow icon, as I said in my post.

Comment: I have applied this method before this answer,  And Worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` causes `ListView` to rebuild everything. It will remove its child views, call `getView()` for all the items that are visible, and thus you will rebind all the data for those items.

But your *data* hasn't actually changed. You haven't modified anything in the questions list, so binding the data again is meaningless. Instead you have tried to change something in your `ViewHolder` object, but there's no guarantee that the `convertView` you get after a `notifyDataSetChanged()` is for the same position as before, so it's possible that some *other* item has been affected (or perhaps none at all?).

Try removing the call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` from the `OnClickListener`. A visibility change should cause a re-layout of the view hierarchy, but as long as you haven't told `ListView` that the data has changed, it should keep all its current children.

Comment: I am little confused after reading your answer. Sorry for that. I understood that, notifyDataSetChanged() is meaningless as there is no data change. I have removed it. But still it is not working. I did not understand this part : "A visibility change should cause a re-layout of the view hierarchy, but as long as you haven't told ListView that the data has changed, it should keep all its current children." Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee When a View changes from VISIBLE to GONE (or vice versa), it calls `requestLayout()`. Android needs to measure, layout, and draw the view hierarchy in order to show the new state. ListView is a ViewGroup; it has children, it measures them, lays them out, and draws them. If you call notifyDataSetChanged, LIstView removes its children and builds new ones (which then are measured, layed out, and drawn). I suggest not calling that, in order for ListView to measure/layout/draw the children it already has, including the one who changed visibility.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee It might be worth trying to use RecyclerView instead of ListView. ListView was designed to be in complete control of its children, including clicks, and so you would provide an `OnItemClickListener`. Making certain sub-regions of those children clickable has always been a little quirky. RecyclerView takes the opposite approach: it basically does nothing besides the recycling, so the views themselves can receive clicks and do more intricate things.

Comment: Nice explanation. But is listview giving any method to just invalidate and show it. I already removed the notifiyDatasetChanged(). Previously I also worked with listview similar things. But it was not hide/show some of the items. It is really tough to move back again RecyclerView.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee You could try calling `invalidate()` on the ListView, which should make it redraw only, but I don't think that will be useful either. I still recommend switching to RecyclerView, it's not that much different if you are making relatively simple lists.

Comment: so,  according to your last line, how to told to listview ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the adapter, e.g `Adapter myAdapter = new Adapter`, set it to a `listview` or `recyclerview` e.g `listview.setAdapter(mydapter)` and everytime you add new data to it call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: jumps the listview in 0 position